# blank pages in html2pdf

Tags: angular, html2pdf

When the table is very large (for example 50 rows with 10 columns) the pdf is generating as blank pages.

I'm using the below code to export the html as pdf while on Click the "Export PDF" button.

```
var element = document.getElementById('showPrintContent');
html2pdf(element, {
  margin: 0,
  filename: this.opportunity.opportunityName + '.pdf',
  image: {
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 0.98
  },
  html2canvas: {
    dpi: 192,
    letterRendering: true
  },
  jsPDF: {
    unit: 'in',
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'portrait'
  }
});
```

Comment: So it works fine if the table is much smaller?

Comment: @callback Yes its works fine for lesser content.